# Exciting Data from live site add to pgAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, pgadmin

I would like to add existing database from our live site into pgAdmin.

I have downloaded the file from our live site.
I have pgAdmin set up with the databases (development and test) how do I add the existing database data to pgAdmin?

Comment: It depends on the format of the import data.

Comment: TextEdit 
I tired in pgAdmin > server > database > restore

Comment: Is TextEdit a text editor? The import needs to be in a format the database can interpret, or you need create appropriate structures within your local database and import it in pieces.  Why are you trying to import text into the database?

Comment: All I did was download it from the live database. I didn't get an option on format.

Comment: What live database?

Comment: from the ruby on rails application live site on heroku